# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in

Tags: php, poo, pdo

buenas gente tengo problemas para conectar con la base de datos desde mi host ,me pide cambiar los nombres del metodo de_construct ya que tengo el mismo nombre de la clase pero luego me salta que no se encuentra la query

esta es la conexion que estoy tratando de pasar de mi localhost

```
<?php 
   class Conexion {
       protected $base;
       public function Connect() {
           try{
               $this->base = new PDO('mysql:host=fdb29.awardspace.net; dbname=ejemplo1','ejemplo1','contraseña');
               $this->base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
               $this->base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
               return $this->base;
           } catch(Exception $e) { 
               echo "Error en la linea: " . $e->getline();
           }
       } 
   }
```

el error me sale aqui ,haciendo referencia a "$statement = $this->base->query($sql);"

```
include_once 'conexion.php';
    class Mangas extends Conexion {
        public function Mangas(){
            parent::__construct();
        }
        public function mangaUsuario(){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM manga ORDER BY manga.id ASC";
            $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
            $statement->execute(array());
            $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
            $statement->closeCursor();
            return $resultado;
        }
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /srv/disk21/3798063/www/mcd13lscans.ga/bin/clases.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /srv/disk21/3798063/www/mcd13lscans.ga/_admin/panelAdmin.php(60): Mangas->mangaUsuario() #1 /srv/disk21/3798063/www/mcd13lscans.ga/_admin/panel.php(23): require_once('/srv/disk21/379...') #2 {main} thrown in /srv/disk21/3798063/www/mcd13lscans.ga/bin/clases.php on line 9

Comment: Esto: `$this->base->query($sql);` debería ser así: `$this->Connect()->query($sql);`

Comment: Hermano mil gracias,pensaba que no me iban a responder

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿por qué `Mangas` extiende de `Conexion`? ¿Acaso son parientes? ¿Realmente un objeto `Mangas` es en cierto sentido una `Conexion` o comparte propiedades con esa entidad? Puede que en tu modelo de datos haya un error de diseño, eso se aprecia por ejemplo en el hecho de que la clase extiende del padre, y llamas al constructor del padre sin pasarle nada. ¿Cómo explicas eso? Parece que esas dos clases realmente no deberían relacionarse mediante herencia.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<?php

class Uno 
{
    public $mensajeAqui;
    
    public function asignaMensaje(): string
    {
        $this->mensajeAqui = 'Algo';
        return $this->mensajeAqui;
    }
}

class Dos extends Uno
{
    public function leeMensaje(): string
    {
        return $this->asignaMensaje();
    }
}

var_dump((new Dos())->leeMensaje());
var_dump((new Dos())->mensajeAqui);
```

- La primera instancia nos dará `NULL`
- La segunda nos dará `string(4) "Algo"`

De hecho si la propiedad la manejo de manera tipada colocando por ejemplo:

```
public string $mensajeAqui;
```

Y sigo con el código anterior, la segunda instancia me daría este error:

> Uncaught Error: Typed property Uno::$mensajeAqui must not be accessed before initialization in

Lo anterior:

> Es precisamente para **ejemplificar** el problema que enfrentas, la variable es **`NULL`** y sobre ese *valor* tratas de ejecutar una consulta por medio del método `query()` lo cual en efecto **no funcionará.**

Luego entonces te comento lo siguiente:

1. En tu clase `Conexion` movería el retorno de `$base` a nivel del alcance de la función quedando así:

   ```
   public function Connect()
   {
       .........................
       .........................
       try {

       } catch() {

       }

       return $this->base;
   }
   ```
2. Ahora en la clase `Mangas` que ya esta heredando de `Conexion` yo quitaría el siguiente segmento

   ```
   public function Mangas()
   {
        parent::__construct();
   }
   ```

Debido a que:

- Yo no veo un método constructor en tu clase padre
- No tiene caso en la clase Mangas (*al menos no bajo el contexto actual*)

Por último:

3. Para acceder al objeto de la conexión a quien debes invocar es a `Connect()` y no a la propiedad que retorna quedando así:

   ```
   $statement = $this->Connect()->query($sql);
   ```
4. Por otro lado ya que no estás pasando valores dinámicos para construir tu consulta entonces no tiene sentido práctico que pases un array vacio a tu método execute.

Entonces quitaría esto:

```
$statement->execute(array());
```

Y con esto debería alcanzar:

```
$statement = $this->Connect()->query($sql);
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta agregando esos detalles @MCDIEL